# Unable to send mail via Mailgun over api or smtp

Tags: mailgun

I have setup a new account and not verified my domain. I would like to test and confirm mail-send before proceeding with verification and adding payment information.

I have tried curl using the sandbox method and api key (including smtp). I have also tried to use my domain using the top account mail-address as recipient. But each time the send command (both curl and smtp) I get "Mailgun Magnificent API" response - but no mail is delivered. So far the Mailgun API does not look so Magnificent... I have gone through the documentation multiple times and cannot find what I might be doing wrong..

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Faced the same issue while sending emails via api by php curl. I solved it by changing API Base URL https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME to https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages.
It's because their api is not only for sending.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Apparently they need to move me to a more reputed IP and it seems to work now. Although I had made the mistake to not using 'messages' earlier and that was one of the problems that I had already fixed.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone else trying to figure out what **"Mailgun Magnificent API"** means in a Mailgun HTTP 200-OK API response, it occurs when posting to `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/some/api/endpoint` when `/some/api/endpoint` is not a valid Mailgun API endpoint.

**If you are using a client library,** there's probably a mistake in your Mailgun sender domain setting. Say you've verified the domain *mg.example.com* with Mailgun. Examples that can result in "Mailgun Magnificent API" (the exact setting name depends on the library):

- `MAILGUN_DOMAIN = mg.example.com # comment`—this is a common mistake in dotenv files, which don't usually support inline comments; move the `# comment` to its own line
- `MAILGUN_DOMAIN = mg.example.com/mysite`—get rid of the `/mysite` part

**If you are posting directly to the Mailgun API** (or developing a client library), there are some additional ways you might get "Mailgun Magnificent API":

- Omitting the API endpoint: `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.example.com` (as noted in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45391544/647002) response)
- Misspelling the endpoint: `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.example.com/massages` (that should be m*e*ssages with an *e*)
- Including a `#` or `?` after your domain: `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.example.com #/messages` (see the note above about comments in config files)
- Including an extra path after your domain: `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.example.com/route/to/my/app/messages`

Note that you won't see "Mailgun Magnificent API" if YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME is not a valid sending domain you've registered with Mailgun. (In that case, Mailgun instead responds 404-Not Found).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I simply didn't uncomment MAILGUN_DOMAIN and KEY. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The mailgun guide shows you to use *https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN* as YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME as in the snippet below and ***this was the problem***.

If you're using mailgun-js, you simply need to have ***YOUR_DOMAIN*** as YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.

No need for the *https://api.mailgun.net/v3* part

```html
const API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
const DOMAIN = 'YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME';
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: API_KEY, domain: DOMAIN});

const data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'foo@example.com, bar@example.com',
  subject: 'Hello',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, (error, body) => {
  console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Including an slash "/" after messages url part at the end causes this failure too.

For example if you are using a library like [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) for c#, ensure your service interface  be declared like this (see the Post attribute):

```
public interface IMailgunService
{
    [Post("")]
    Task<JsonDocument> SendEmailAsync([Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)] Dictionary<string, object> data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was not including my domain name in the url and trying to type everything onto a single line. Strictly following their online example. Typing a backslash will bring your cursor to a new line.

```
$ curl -s --user 'api:key-xxx' \
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/your_domain/messages \
-F from='User <user@sample.mailgun.org>' \
-F to='xxx@gmail.com' \
-F subject='Hello' \
-F text='Testing some mailgun!'
```

Response

```
{
  "id": "<xxx.x.xxx@your_domain>",
  "message": "Queued. Thank you."
}
```