# curl_exec returns message but email is not sent

Tags: php, mailgun, php-curl

I am using PHP version 7.1.9 with mailgun. Right now I am attempting to build the email portion of my code and I am using the following:

```
function send_email($from, $to, $subject, $body) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:[api found under domains > sandbox > API Key]');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '[url found under domains > sandbox > API Base URL]');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'from' => $from,
        'to' => $to,
        'subject' => $subject,
        'text' => $body
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Whenever I execute the code the `send_email` function it returns the following String via the echo method:

> Mailgun Magnificent API

Which to me, signifies that it successfully executed the function, however I never actually receive the email. Why would I get this echoed message, but not the email?

Some background information:

- Currently I am debugging locally via XAMPP v3.2.2 on my local host(127.0.0.1)
- As pointed out in the curl_setopt values, I am using the sandbox domain for testing purposes (I've masked them out in the code for obvious reasons)
- The email that I am sending to **is** verified in the *Authorized Recipients* section of the sandbox domain
- The *Outgoing* column under the sandbox domain confirms that 0 emails have been sent

Comment: and what do mailgun have to say?

Comment: try `var_dump($result);` instead of echo.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz - I added the var_dump just prior to the return statement in the function and the following was returned: `string(23) "Mailgun Magnificent API"`

Comment: Here's a [very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255915/unable-to-send-mail-via-mailgun-over-api-or-smtp).

Comment: @LuisMuñoz - Thank you very much! Adding the `/messages` suffix solved the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that.