# "Mailgun Magnificent API" error with Django-Anymail in docker on Digital Ocean

Tags: django, docker, digital-ocean, mailgun, django-anymail

I am running a django application running on docker
and I am using django-anymail to send emails via mailgun.

When I go through for example a forgot my password process I am getting an error in django-anymail:

> **AnymailRequestsAPIError: Invalid JSON in Mailgun API response**
>   Sending a message to *testemail@test.com* from info@*application*.co.uk 
>   Mailgun API response 200 (OK): 'Mailgun Magnificent API' 
>   @ anymail/backends/base_requests.py in deserialize_json_response at line 106

I am able to re-create this error if I `docker exec -it` onto the django container and run the following in a `python manage.py shell`

```py
from django.core.mail import send_mail 
customer_email = send_mail('Test','Test','info@*application*.co.uk',["*test@test.com*"],fail_silently=False)
```

If I run this after building and running my `production.yml` docker locally it works and I get an email but if I run this on the container on my digital ocean droplet I receive an error.

Is there a configuration I am missing in order to get this working? I have another django application just running on a droplet(no docker) and it works fine with mailgun using the same setup.

Comment: What are your anymail settings?

Comment: If someone else comes across this be sure to check your MAILGUN_API_URL to have either `https://api.mailgun.net/v3` for Mailgun’s US service or `https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3` for Mailgun’s European service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error "Mailgun Magnificent API" is most likely caused by a `#` character in your MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN. That often happens when you try to use line-end comments in a config file format that doesn't support them—like dotenv:

```
# .env
MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN=mail.example.com  # INVALID: dotenv doesn't allow comment here
```

If you upgrade to [django-anymail v6.0](https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog/#v6-0), you'll get an improved error message that makes this more obvious.

([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54774987/647002) covers other situations that can lead to "[Mailgun Magnificent API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54774987/647002).")

Comment: Thank you very much. It was indeed an issue with MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN. Also thank you for improving the title..much more useful. Have a good weekend!