# Mailgun API responding with Ok status but emails are not being sent (Sandbox)

Tags: c#, mailgun

I've set up a Mailgun account and created the sample class they provide.

I've added my mail as an authorized email. WHen I run the code below, I get a status of OK (or completed) but mails aren't being sent.

The context of the response is "Mailgun Magnificent API" and I've tryed everything suggested here: [Unable to send mail via Mailgun over api or smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255915/unable-to-send-mail-via-mailgun-over-api-or-smtp)
but none of them seem to be the problem. (i tried with messeges after the URL)

[image]

There's also this exception in the output window, but it doesn't cause the program to stop. Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll

[image]

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = SendSimpleMessage();
    Console.WriteLine(a.Content.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static IRestResponse SendSimpleMessage()
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox<bla-bla>.mailgun.org");
    client.Authenticator =
        new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
            "<api-key>");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    request.AddParameter("domain", "sandbox<bla-bla>.mailgun.org", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
    request.AddParameter("from", "Phil <mailgun@sandbox<bla-bla>.mailgun.org>");
    request.AddParameter("to", "me@gmail.com");
    request.AddParameter("subject", "Hello");
    request.AddParameter("text", "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!");
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    var v = client.Execute(request);
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting out this line

```
//request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
```

and adding /messages here

```
client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox<bla-bla>.mailgun.org/messages");
```

fixed it

Comment: What's the technical reason behind this answer? Did you find out?