# TypeError on attempting to send email via nodemailer & mailgun

Tags: nodemailer, mailgun

I am trying to get nodemail and nodemail-mailgun to send an email. (Eventually form submission results).

I have tried searching on SO as well as just general google and I cannot seem to find someone with the same issue.

The Setup:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mg = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const auth = {
  auth: {
    api_key: 'REMOVED FOR SECURITY',
    domain: 'REMOVED FOR SECURITY'
  }
}

  const nodemailerMailgun = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(auth));
```

The Route:

```
router.post('/contact', function(req, res, next) {

  console.log('Send Mail...');

  nodemailerMailgun.sendMail({
    from: "no-reply@airsafetynw.com",
    to: 'john.s@airsafetynw.com', // An array if you have multiple recipients.
    cc:'adam.f.wilkinson@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Air Safety NW contact form',
    //You can use "html:" to send HTML email content. It's magic!
    html: '<b>From:</b></br>',
    //You can use "text:" to send plain-text content. It's oldschool!
    text: ""
  }, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    }
    else {
      res.send('Successful!')
    }
  });

});
```

The Error:

> asnw > Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>
> POST /contact - - ms - -

I have removed ALL js variables in my template in hopes that maybe one of them was incorrect however if I res.send or console.log the req.body.variable above the .sendmail they work just fine. If someone knows where I can look for the 'id' so I can figure out what is not defined I might be able to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your mailgun auth domain should be of the form sandboxbXXX.mailgun.org not https://app.mailgun.com/app/sending/domains/sandboxbXXX.mailgun.org

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your DOMAIN variable could be the problem.

Instead of setting DOMAIN variable to https://api.mailgun.net/v3/DOMAIN, simply set it to DOMAIN

For example, set it to ***mg.website.org*** and not https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.website.org

See
[Unable to send mail via Mailgun over api or smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255915/unable-to-send-mail-via-mailgun-over-api-or-smtp/65289937#65289937)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need nodemailer-mailgun-transport, nodemailer is able to send the mail all alone.

here is the code which i use to send email only using nodemailer and it work fine for me.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

const transferEmail_details = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true, // use TLS
  auth: {
    user: authAdmin@gmail.com,
    pass: admin123
  },
  tls: {
    // do not fail on invalid certs
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
})

var nodemailer_Option =
{
  from: 'customer@gmail.com',
  to: 'authAdmin@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Complain',
  text: 'abc' ,
  html : '<h1>Hello</h1>'
}


transferEmail_details.sendMail(nodemailer_Option, function (err, info) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(info , 'Message sent: ' );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Saad but I am trying to use the API and SMTP.

Comment: Saad,I noticed I had a typo earlier. I dont want to use the SMTP through the mailgun service as I dont want to go through all the domain setup. The cc email address in the route is strickly for my testing purposes. I just wanted to use the API as I  wouldnt have to worry about all the extra setup that goes along with it. However, That might be part of my issue. As for now I am going to use google SMTP while I try and figure out the rest.